# For Indian in Bulgaria, how to get Schengen visa to travel to Germany

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, bulgaria

I've come to Bulgaria(Sofia) for 3 months on official trip, with Type C - Bulgarian visa.
I don't have a valid schengen visa. I need to travel to Germany on official trip for one week. Also planning to travel to Switzerland on personal trip. Can I apply for Schengen visa in Bulgaria, from German consulate ?
Last year June, I travelled to France, Switzerland (entry through Paris and exit through Zurich) but the Schengen visa expired already. I travelled to U.K. as well last year but the visa expired as well. I have travelled to US last year and I have a valid B1 visa.

Thanks and Regards,
Traveler...

Answer (score 1):

Generally you *should* apply at the consulate for your place of residence. You can apply at the consulate for the place where you actually are if going to your place of residence would be undue hardship.

With your application, be prepared to explain why the trip to Germany was surprising and did not come up until you had come to Bulgaria, and why you cannot reasonably return to India first.